# Define pre-processor flag in one project and use it in another

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have a notification service responsible for emailing a variety of external clients based on specific criteria's. Obviously, we route all notifications using pre-processor directives to internal emails when testing in QA. I have a suite of unit tests that verify which email address will be used. Problem I have is that my unit tests verify whether criteria foo (for example) would send an email to client #1. But, due to our pre-processor flags, always fails.

Is it possible to set pre-processor flags in one project (i.e. unit test project) and use it in another? This way I could set a flag (e.g. TESTING) and check it in my main project. If the TESTING flag is set, then don't route notifications to local addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the symbols you can define for C# projects can be defined in two places:

1. In the project configuration
2. In the .cs file itself

The first will only impact the project for which it is set.

Additionally, these symbols are used during compilation, and whole sections of code is simply ignored depending on where you place these symbols. As such, by the time you compile the unit-test project, which has a reference back to the assembly under test, that assembly has already been compiled.

You're going to have to use a different mechanism for this.

Have you considered dependency injection? Inject a behavior to the system which dictates where/how the messages would be routed, which you can replace with a mock or a stub during test to override.

Answer (score 1):

As Lasse V. Karlsen says, dependency injection is the *proper* way to deal with this requirement. It's definitely better to inject different behaviours into your code, rather than to rely on compiler flags etc.

Having said that, there is another option that will allow you to work around this if rewriting the app to support DI isn't an option at this time:

1. Create a new "main application test" project
2. Set the `TESTING` pre-processoe flag in this new project
3. Right-click on the project and select "Add existing item". Ensure you select "Add as link" and then select all the files from your main project.

You can now link your unit-test project to this new one. Because the files are added as links, they still only exist in the main project, so changes automatically "appear" in the test version too. Don't forget to "Add as link" any new files though.